Why did German typewriters not use Fraktur?
Fraktur was the dominant typeface in Germany for centuries until the Nazis suddenly stopped using it in WWII.
I read citation needed that the Nazis, before they suddenly marked Fraktur as "Jewish" in 1941, tried to introduce Fraktur typewriters in 1933 but quickly gave up.
That inspired my questions: Why were German typewriters not using Fraktur in the first place?
The Nazis stopped using Fraktur in 1941, officially because they marked it "Jewish", but probably because they found it impractical for their "empire" with many non-German speaking regions. But typewriters are much older than that. I wonder, if someone build a typewriter in Germany in 1920, why did they use Antiqua (latin letters) instead of Fraktur?

You write 'suddenly stopped using'. Any reason why? That might be your clue.

First, simply putting 'Fraktur typewriter' into a search engine yields some pictures of typewrites with Fraktur keys, so they exist/existed. Second, I would remove the Nazi-Germany tag from your question. Typerwriters where in usage well before the 1940s and so I would understand your question as mostly referring to the time from 1880 until 1940 (invention of typewriter until end of Fraktur use).

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). At a minimum, all questions should explain why Wikipedia is insufficient.

Question is predicated on the unsupported assumption that there were no (few) Fraktur typewriters. I'd believe that research to support that assumption might resolve the larger question.

@MCW I now also see that my research was insufficient.

This is a great opportunity to do some "experimental history" - or at least review results of others who practice it.
Think about how a typewriter works - a small metal letter picks up ink and slaps it onto paper. Because paper is made up of absorbent fibers, that ink is going to quickly spread a little bit before it dries (the typographic term is "bleeding").
The effect is that a letter appears bolder than it actually is. That's why Roman style typewriter letter forms are designed with wide-open counters, so that when the ink bleeds you can still have a page that looks like this (from the very first commercial typewriter, the 1856 Hansen Writing Ball):

Now let's look at Fraktur. This is, to use informal language, a "gothic" script that evolved from medieval writing. As such, it is adapted well to the broadnib pen - crisp, thick vertical strokes with thin horizontal additions and flourishes.
This looks awful on a typewriter. You can see how the letters bleed together into a nasty blob of ink in the thicker sections, or fail to pick up enough ink in the thinner sections (the descender on the , as well as every capital letter). This destroys a lot of the features that make Fraktur readable.

Compare that to even a newspaper, where the low quality paper is nevertheless able to preserve the fine lines due to the printing process being far more kind to this sort of script. Observe the radical difference in closed letterforms like , , , or  (although  is clearly struggling in both cases).

It was possible to get around those limitations - for example the type specimen below spaces out the letters to 2 or even 3 times normal - but it's not a tradeoff that Roman type had to make, and along with other factors (the lack of bold and italics for emphasis, and the popularity of Roman over Fraktur in the world economy) served to suppress demand for Fraktur, and Fraktur typewriters as a consequence.

The Fraktur samples here are from machines manufactured in 1903 and 1926 respectively, well before the rise of the Nazis. So German typewriters (some of them!) were definitely still using Fraktur, and improving it. Look at how much clearer the second specimen is! 23 years of progress are plainly visible, but they are still a far cry from the open, highly rounded forms of the Roman type, developed over time into Courier and similar typefaces.

The constraints on Fraktur's letterforms meant that it was just not competitive with the popularity and clarity that Roman type was able to achieve. Note the description of the 1926 machine: Roman keys with Fraktur slugs, already a partial capitulation to the dominant script.

I think the correct typographic term is "ink squash" as "bleed" refers to intentional extension of an inked area beyond and intended cut or trim line. For halftones it would be "dot gain"

"a small metal letter picks up liquid ink and slaps it onto paper" Not really. A typewriter presses a letter form (metal, at that time) into a ribbon (fabric, at that time), which transfers the ink (liquid, at that time) in the ribbon onto the paper. The issue is with the limited flexibility of the fabric results in the transfer of ink around the type. The fabric has to be thick enough to retain ink for multiple impressions and last through several re-inkings. This is why at the end of the typewriter's life, they switched to much thinner single-use plastic ribbons and solid ink.

I didn't really want to get into the details but yes.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany: Now you're making me feel old...

What should also be mentioned is that fraktur is really not intended to be monospaced. For example, the vertical strokes of all the "i", "u", "n", and "m" in a word like  ought to be equidistant, so an "m" should in effect be three times as wide as an "i"

@HagenvonEitzen: Proportional spacing mechanical typewriters did exist, though I'm not sure the timescales would have matched.

@user71659  "The fabric has to be thick enough to retain ink for multiple impressions"  Maybe that doesn't read the way you would like it to, but the ribbon moves one character-width at a time, precisely so that a fresh portion is used for each key-strike. More modern typewriters even used plastic-film which had the interesting side effect of making it trivial to read what had been typed with it!

@MikeB The original typewriter ribbons used a short strip of thicker fabric that was cycled back and forth until its ink was completely depleted (and that was often re-inked at that point to save on cost), rather than the later one-directional thinner ribbons where every position was struck only once.

@HagenvonEitzen To be fair, the "not intended to be monospaced" is true for Roman types as well, which is why a book set in Courier Mono would look... awkward.

German Wikipedia says, the Germans did try use Fraktur typewriters:

In the first half of the 20th century, there were also typewriters with Fraktur types in the German-speaking world. These generally had the typical Fraktur ligatures ch, ck, tz, st and the long s as additional characters. Typewriter fracture was not standardized, i.e. there were several versions. [...]
However, the Fraktur fonts did not catch on on the typewriter, as they were very difficult to read as non-proportional typewriter fonts. Attempts to equip typewriters with proportional Fraktur fonts also failed.

